# Cant Get Script in Dialog To Work

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a page that invokes a dialog.

Within my code I am including the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./croppie/croppie.css" />
<script src="./croppie/croppie.js"></script>
```

The dialog is invoked using the code below but the include js file is not rendering properly:

```
$('#upload_img_btn').on('click', function() {
    var data = "<input id=filename1 name='__files[]' type='file' single /> <div class = 'profile-image' style='width: 130px; margin-left: 300px; margin-top:200px; width:200px; height: 200px; display:block;'><img class='crop-image' src='./train4.jpg'></div>";
    $('#upload_image').dialog('option', 'title', 'Upload Image');
    $('#upload_image').html(data).dialog('open');
    $('input');
});
```

If I move the html for the dialog (see var data statement above) to the main html area within the file it displays properly (although not as a dialog which is not desired). So clearly the js script needed by the dialog is not available to it for it to render properly.  How do I make the js script available to the dialog?

Comment: What do you mean by "not rendering properly"? What does it look like? What about "move the html for the second dialog ... to the main html area within the file"? Do you mean a `<script>` element? What happens if you write `$(function() { $('#upload_img_btn')... etc });`?

Comment: The script that is not getting loaded creates the necessary style elements and provides the methods for allowing the image to be cropped.  The issue is that the I need the js file to be loaded with the second dialog.

Comment: Also not sure why I stated that there was a second dialog.  There is only one dialog and I have updated the problem description accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer to my own question.  It turns out that jquery strips script tags from html returned to the dialog unless explicitly told not to.

Modifying the statement:

```
$('#upload_image').html(data).dialog('open');
```

To:

```
$('#upload_image').html(data).dialog('open', document, true);
```

solved the problem.